# Where to place the drawing code in a JPanel used as canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jpanel, paintcomponent

I've a JPanel where I'm drawing with the mouse events and **after resizing, or minimizing-restoring it, it doesnt display what has to be drawn**, despite a "degub" println shows me the function is being called, but for some reason, it reamains blank

I thought I should have added my drawing function in the paintComponent function but it seems not to be working right, so what I'm doing wrong or where should I place that drawElements() call?

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawElements();
}
void drawElements() {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    for (Element el : elements) {
        el.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post a runnable example

Comment: Also, I don't know how drawElements() works because you don't pass the Graphics object to the method.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the drawing proccess, because on mouse click it draws a single element and it works perfect. If I replace the drawing one element for drawing them all it works as well.
So it's something related to how this internally works that I'm not understanding

Comment: Pass the graphics object to the drawElements method

Comment: Indeed, @rafalopez79's suggestion is the correct answer.  I've reproduced your exact issue with a simple example and passing the graphics object in instead of calling getGraphics() fixes it.

Comment: Thank you guys, that fixed the problem! Do you know the reason why the problem happened and why this fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the graphics object to the drawElements method.

(Right answer provided by @rafalopez79)